# Calculating $n$-th power of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I was doing an exercise of a past exam in which one of the things I had to do was calculating the $n$<sup>th</sup> power of a Jordan matrix
$$J=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}.$$
I started calculating until the 5th power but I couldn't guess the expression for the $a_{1,2}$, $a_{1,3}$ and $a_{2,3}$ components. When I looked it up in an online calculator it showed that:

$$J^n=\begin{pmatrix}
2^n & \frac{2^n·n}{2} & \frac{2^n·(n^2-n)}{8} \\
0 & 2^n & \frac{2^n·n}{2} \\
0 & 0 & 2^n
\end{pmatrix}.$$

My question is: when the relationships are as difficult as these　(especially the $a_{1,3}$ component), are there any tricks for figuring out the$n$<sup>th</sup> power component? Because these kind of relationships are difficult to think in the middle of an exam.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint :**
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix} = 2 I+\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Actually I tried calculating it this way, but I couldn't guess the relation :/
I calculated the power as $J^n=(2I+M)^n$, where $M$ is the second matrix you wrote.

Comment: @AlbertoDeCelisRomero Well, you don't have to "guess" the relation : just expand with the Newton's binomial formula (because $2I$ and $M$ commute), and see that because $M^3=0$, just three terms remain.

Answer (score 4):

$J=2I+A$, where $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0 \\0&0&1 \\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$. As $A$ and $I$ commute, we can apply the binomial formula.

Observe that  $A^2=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&1 \\0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$, $A^k=0$ for $k\ge 3$, so the $n$-th power is
$$J^n=2^n I+n2^{n-1}A+\frac{n(n-1) 2^{n-2} }2A^2=2^n I+n2^{n-1}A+n(n-1) 2^{n-3}A^2. $$

Comment: Oh sorry didn't see the answer. Thank you very much for your help! It's very useful! So you can only do this when the matrices commute, right?

Comment: @AlbertoDeCelisRomero: yes. More generally, in a ring, you can apply the binomial formula if the elements commute.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Expand

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n+1} & b_{n+1} & c_{n+1} \\
0 & d_{n+1} & e_{n+1} \\
0 & 0 & f_{n+1}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
a_n & b_n & c_n \\
0 & d_n & e_n \\
0 & 0 & f_n
\end{pmatrix}$$

and contemplate the six linear recurrence relations you obtain. ($a,d,f$ are immediate.)

---

**Additional hint:**

The characteristic polynomial is $(2-\lambda)^3$ so the matrix has a triple Eigenvalue $2$, and you can expect the expressions of the elements of the powers to be in the form of $2^n$ times a quadratic polynomial in $n$.

Comment: I haven't heard about the additional hint you have said before. Is there any theorem I can look for to see when is this true? It can help a lot in future exercises! 

From the relation $a_{n+1}=2a_n$ I suppose that $a_n=d_n=f_n=2^n$ right?
Nevertheless for $b_{n+1}$ the relation is $b_{n+1}=2b_n+d_n=2(b_n+2^{n-1})$, which is only true for $n=4$. For $n=3$ we would have $12=2(4+4)$ which is not true, and for $n=5$ we have $80=2(32+2^4)$, which is also false. Am I having a mistake here?

Comment: Ah, I just noticed a mistake in it XD, it's true for all $n$

Comment: But still I don't understand well how to get the expression $2^{n-1}n$ for $b_n$ :/